# When Webassembly will support all the basic data types?

Tags: webassembly

When wasm will support all the data types like `Strings, Array, bool` etc.

I could see in doc data types supporting only i32, i64,f32,f64 https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/Semantics.md#types

When can we expect other data types support? what is the effort going on?

Answer (score 4):

Soon, via the [garbage collection proposal](https://github.com/WebAssembly/gc/blob/master/proposals/gc/Overview.md), but probably not in quite the way you are expecting!

WebAssembly is a relatively low-level language and virtual machine, much closer to a real CPU than a higher-level language like JavaScript. As a result, it only supports a few numeric types. This is being extended in a few different ways:

- One is the ongoing work on [reference types](https://github.com/WebAssembly/reference-types/blob/master/proposals/reference-types/Overview.md), which allows WebAssembly to hold references to objects created by the host, e.g. a reference to a JavaScript object.
- Another is the garbage collection proposal, however the proposal states that it will have *Low-level data representation types, not high-level language types or object model*.

All this doesn't mean that languages that compile to WebAssembly cannot support more complex data types like strings, structs and arrays - and indeed, you'll find that C#, AssemblyScript and Rust all support a rich type system, whilst still compiling to WebAssembly.

Comment: But the garbage collection is not the most minimal possible as it still have some type of types.

Comment: But if I use `String` data type from Rust and compile it to wasm, i can't move forward because wasm only recognises memory as `pointers`. I need to write rust code as (u8) pointer. 

So that i was asking about commonly used data types support

Comment: If you use wasm-bindgen crate in Rust, it will do all the conversion steps for you. Then in Rust code you can use `&str` for a JS string. In background wasm-bindgen will do the byte array conversion hacks. wasm-bindgen also helps with objects and other data types. And the best: it's relatively fast ding it.